# Laravel Migration Create User "unexpected 'use' (T_USE)" SQLite

Tags: laravel, sqlite, symfony

I'm using the latest version of Laravel. Fresh project. Just created the make:auth function.

My goal was to add additional fields to the registration field. The original model only requires name, email and password. I'm using SQLite and PHP 7.1.19

I wanted to add first name, last name and age. Somehow I'm getting the error shown below.

Could someone elaborate on what I'm doing wrong?

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) at /Users/sebastiaan/Documents/Code/auth/auth-example/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php:3
        1| <?php
        2|  
      > 3| use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
        4| use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
        5| use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
        6| 
        7| class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
        8| {
        9|     /**

      Exception trace:

      1   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::requireOnce("/Users/sebastiaan/Documents/Code/auth/auth-example/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php")
          /Users/sebastiaan/Documents/Code/auth/auth-example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:448

      2   Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator::requireFiles()
          /Users/sebastiaan/Documents/Code/auth/auth-example/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php:90

      Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

This is how the migration file is looking right now.

```
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: Hello @NicoHaase I'm using php version 7.1.19(cli)

Comment: And how exactly do you call that migration script?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm calling the migration with "php artisan migrate" and I also tried "php artisan migrate:fresh"

Answer (score 4):

Namespace and use statements are not supported in PHP versions < `5.3`

Please check your php version using `<?php echo phpversion(); ?>` and check if its lower than 5.3

Otherwise the class looks good. If you had whitespaces at the start before the starting php tag, you would receive a different error like

> Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

which seems not the case as well.

Update :

Another way it can happen is due to some characters just before use statement. For example this code :

```
<?php 

test

use \App\User;

class....
?>
```

If you observe the presence `test` word before the use statement by mistake this would cause the same error.

Coming back to how this is relevant here :

If you have copied your migration class from some website in case, you may have copied some unnoticeable white space characters as well. I will suggest do a backspace before use statement and check for such whitespaces. If you open this file in VIM editor, you might see such cases as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked my PHP version and I'm on PHP 7.1.19 using a Macbook Air 2018.

Comment: @S-o have you tested with `<?php echo phpversion(); ?>` as pointed by the answer? Remembering that PHP cli and PHP cgi can have different versions (see more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php)

Comment: @S-o Then you also want to run `php --version`, since you are using a PHP command, and make sure your cli and cgi versions do match.

Comment: Also check that if you are using containers like vagrant boxes, the php version installed on your parent mac machine will not matter and you will have to check the php web version (not cli) in the container(e.g vagrant/docker) box, Best way is to do phpversion() in your index.php file

Comment: @b.enoit.be I echo'ed the php version in the homepage of the fresh Laravel page. It says "7.1.19", the same version as my CLI. They match.

Comment: @MihirBhende I echo'ed the php version in the homepage of the fresh Laravel page. It says "7.1.19", the same version as my CLI. They match.

Comment: Check my updated answer with one more way to identify this error

Comment: @MihirBhende Thank you for taking the effort. I just fixed the issue I had. I'm not sure how or why, but I rebuild the website and used sqlite. With every step of code I added I did a migrate:fresh to see when it would crash. Somehow, it did not crash the second time and I got everything working. I even displayed the logged-in user info on the home page, this is quite an achievement for me. Thank you for your time and effort in helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('users');
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you cite where you got this from if you got it from somewhere else.

Comment: Hello please add additional information as to how/why this answer helps solve the question. Please consider reviewing the answering guidelines stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer